# MSHTML broken page on print

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

I have problems with printed html pages with `mshtml.dll`. My pages contains links to `bootstrap css`. In browser (IE, FF, Chrome) all looks fine and prints also fine. When I trying to print page with `MSHTML` something goes wrong, and page looks like `css` does not work. I am loading html content from disk, and then print it:

```
var htmlContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var htmlDocument = new HTMLDocument() as IHTMLDocument2;
htmlDocument.write(htmlContent);

htmlDocument.execCommand("Print", true, 0);

htmlDocument.styleSheets; // contains all linked css files
```

Does anyone experience such problem? Maybe there are other methods to print html page without browser?